# custom div and css causes form not to submit

Tags: php, html, css, forms

Form is not submitting after adding multiple div's...

The same PHP code used in another document works well, which was downloaded from a simple tutorial, but when I added custom div/CSS to it, it stopped working.

Did I overlook something? I've tried placing the form tags in different positions, but it still is not working.

It's really frustrating since I'm new to coding.

```
<body>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="demor">
            <div class="login">
                <div class="avatar"><img class="img" src="./afb/avatar.png"></div>
                <div class="login__formr">
                    <form action="login.php" method="post">
                        <div class="login__row">
                            <svg class="login__icon name svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M0,20 a10,8 0 0,1 20,0z M10,0 a4,4 0 0,1 0,8 a4,4 0 0,1 0,-8" />
                            </svg>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="login__input name" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login__row">
                            <svg class="login__icon pass svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill="none" d="M17.051,3.302H2.949c-0.866,0-1.567,0.702-1.567,1.567v10.184c0,0.865,0.701,1.568,1.567,1.568h14.102c0.865,0,1.566-0.703,1.566-1.568V4.869C18.617,4.003,17.916,3.302,17.051,3.302z M17.834,15.053c0,0.434-0.35,0.783-0.783,0.783H2.949c-0.433,0-0.784-0.35-0.784-0.783V4.869c0-0.433,0.351-0.784,0.784-0.784h14.102c0.434,0,0.783,0.351,0.783,0.784V15.053zM15.877,5.362L10,9.179L4.123,5.362C3.941,5.245,3.699,5.296,3.581,5.477C3.463,5.659,3.515,5.901,3.696,6.019L9.61,9.86C9.732,9.939,9.879,9.935,10,9.874c0.121,0.062,0.268,0.065,0.39-0.014l5.915-3.841c0.18-0.118,0.232-0.36,0.115-0.542C16.301,5.296,16.059,5.245,15.877,5.362z"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="login__input name" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login__row">
                            <svg class="login__icon pass svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M0,20 20,20 20,8 0,8z M10,13 10,16z M4,8 a6,8 0 0,1 12,0" />
                            </svg>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="login__input pass" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login__row">
                            <svg class="login__icon pass2 svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M10.219,1.688c-4.471,0-8.094,3.623-8.094,8.094s3.623,8.094,8.094,8.094s8.094-3.623,8.094-8.094S14.689,1.688,10.219,1.688M10.219,17.022c-3.994,0-7.242-3.247-7.242-7.241c0-3.994,3.248-7.242,7.242-7.242c3.994,0,7.241,3.248,7.241,7.242C17.46,13.775,14.213,17.022,10.219,17.022 M15.099,7.03c-0.167-0.167-0.438-0.167-0.604,0.002L9.062,12.48l-2.269-2.277c-0.166-0.167-0.437-0.167-0.603,0c-0.166,0.166-0.168,0.437-0.002,0.603l2.573,2.578c0.079,0.08,0.188,0.125,0.3,0.125s0.222-0.045,0.303-0.125l5.736-5.751C15.268,7.466,15.265,7.196,15.099,7.03"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <input type="password" name="cpassword" class="login__input pass" placeholder="Bevestig uw wachtwoord" required/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="register" class="login__submit_r">Registreren</button>
                        <p class="login__signup">Terug naar het &nbsp;<a href="login.php">Loginscherm</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['register'])){
            @$username=$_POST['username'];
            @$password=$_POST['password'];
            @$cpassword=$_POST['cpassword'];
            @$email=$_POST['email'];
            if($password==$cpassword){
                $query = "select * from userinfotbl where username='$username'";
                //echo $query;
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_run){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0){
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This Username Already exists.. Please try another username!")</script>';
                    }
                    else{
                        $query = "insert into userinfotbl values('$username','$password', '$email')";
                        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        if($query_run){
                            header( "Location: homepage.php");
                        }
                        else{
                            echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error. Please try later</p>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("DB error")</script>';
                }
            }
            else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match")</script>';
            }
        }
        else{}
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is the form not submitting? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Works on my machine! What's wrong?

Comment: For starters, try properly indenting your code and separating logic from presentation. Maybe the HTML is invalid, but the way you have it formatted, I don't even think YOU can tell. Also, your `header()` calls are not going to work after content has been sent to the page.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte Ok so it seems to submit but it is not adding the username, password, email into my database... Yet again using the same php code from the other document, it does add them into the database

Comment: Your script is open to SQL injection attacks. To prevent this, you should be using parameterized queries. Also, never store passwords in plain text. Instead, use `password_hash()` and store the password hash, not the password itself.

Comment: @Mike submitting the form puts the hashed password in the database, but if I want to see the actual password myself, how can I do so?

I've used the line: $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: @MertPolat The point of hashing a password is so you and everyone else _can't_ see it.

Comment: @MERTp Nobody, including yourself, should ever see the user's password in plain text except when the user is logging in, and only in memory for that single request (never persisted to storage). To check whether the password provided matches the hash in the database use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `<form action="login.php" method="submit">?`

and Mike has a great point about indenting.

Comment: the fact that you mentioned this fixed my problem.. sort of.. since the documents name was register.php instead of login.php, so changing that made it work.. typical beginners mistake I guess. thanks anway